# Am I using these animation functions correctly?

Tags: jquery

I have an elemnet I would like to fade in, have it on the screen for 5 seconds and then fade out. I have the following:

```
jQuery('#ele').fadeIn(300).delay(5000).fadeOut(300);
```

But the time it stays on the screen seems to be quite sporadic and it frequently vanishes from the screen without fading.

Am I using these functions incorrectly?

I've also tried the following but the results are the same:

```
jQuery('#ele').fadeIn(300);/*delay(5000).fadeOut(300);*/

setTimeout(function() {
    jQuery('#ele').fadeOut(300);
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Works fine to me. http://jsfiddle.net/3etqocs1/

Comment: Both seem to be working fine.

Comment: Works fine for me too : http://jsfiddle.net/8uaddb7p/

Comment: It's inside an app within the Salesforce dev platform, perhaps that's causing some issue... thanks all the same!

Comment: The typical mistake is forgetting to wrap the function call in a jQuery() function.